# cmdline: how to expand `##` in-place?

Tags: cmdline

In Ex mode, `##` can be expanded to the files in the `args` list when files are **expected**, see [`:h cmdline-special`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-special)

> In Ex commands, at places where a file name can be **used**, the following characters have a special meaning.  These can also be used in the expression function expand().

Like `!ls ##` will expand `##` But `echo ##` will not.

However, if I am going to define my own command, how to tell `vim` that I want files here so please expand my `##`?

Is there a way to expand them in place (like how `zsh` expands `*` when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> after it)?

---

An example

```
command! -nargs=1 Echo :exe "echo '" . <q-args> . "'"
```

Now I want to run `Echo I am here ##` with `##` expanded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended in using `cabbr`. This is one way.

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> ##; getcmdtype()==':'?expand('##'):'##;'
cnoreabbrev <expr> #; getcmdtype()==':'?expand('#'):'#;'
cnoreabbrev <expr> %; getcmdtype()==':'?expand('%'):'%;'
```

Another way is to use `cnoremap <expr>`

```
function! s:expand()
  let line = getcmdline()
  let pos = getcmdpos()  " cursor pos
  if pos <= 1
    return ';;'
  endif
  let line = line[0:(pos-2)]
  let match = matchlist(line, '\s\(\(%\|#\|#<\?[0-9]\+\|##\)\(:\S\+\)\?\)$')
  if len(match) < 2 || match[1] == ''
    return ';;'
  else
    return repeat("\<bs>", len(match[1])) . expand(match[1])
  endif
endfunction
cnoremap <expr> ;; <SID>expand()
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`:h expand()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expand%28%29) in your command:

```
command! -nargs=+ Test echo expand("<args>")
```

This way `:Test foo bar` will echo `foo bar` and `:Test ##` will echo your argument list.

About the in-place expansion as far as I know this is not possible out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added an example, I want to achieve that.

Comment: @LiuSha So something like `command! -nargs=* Ls execute ":!ls " . expand("<args>")`?

Comment: Sorry to have confused you, `Ls` is not a good example, because it is a shell command, so that `vim` already knows it should expand it. Here my command is a general purpose command, sometimes I want to show ##, sometimes  it is some other things, like options `-x`.

Comment: @LiuSha Ok with your new example I see what you want to do. I'm not sure there is an elegant way to do it: maybe you could make the command call a function which will treat the arguments as a list and then expand them in a for loop, but that's not really efficient. Maybe someone will come up with a better solution :)